# SQLite 3: two ways to initialize, whats the difference?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

Im new to PDO, SQLite3. There is an example:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm

here is another:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/

both claims that they use SQLite3 - but one uses `new PDO('sqlite:messaging.sqlite3');` while another `new SQLite3` which one should I use? Yes, there are differences, because with the 2nd way, the `setAttribute()` doesnt exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `odbc`, `sql_srv` or many other drivers,  `SQLite` has their own extension called `SQLite3`.

`PDO` extensions is by far the most popular and is compatible with `SQLite`.

I suggest you to use `PDO`, because if you ever decide to switch database system, you will just need to change connection string.

Comment: so the http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/ ? the "new PDO('sqlite:messaging.sqlite3');" then again, how does that string describes its sqlite 3? Only the file extension?

Comment: @JohnSmith this part `sqlite:` with the semi colon tells pdo which driver to use. depending on the DB it could be `myslq:`, `odbc:`, `pgsql:` etc..

Comment: but thats just "sqlite" so it cant be 3

Comment: nevermind, I found other articles, using PDO with the same way, and "sqlite" is actually "sqlite3". Its confusing :)

Comment: @JohnSmith `sqlite3` is just a standalone program that allows you to connect to `sqlite` which is the db file. if you go with pdo you reference `sqlite:`